# Using python 3 how to get co-variance/variance

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression

I have a simple linear regression model and i need to count the variance and the co-variance. How to calculate variance and co-variance using linear regression ?

> Variance, in the context of Machine Learning, is a type of error that occurs due to a model's sensitivity to small fluctuations in the training set.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
X = np.array([2,3,4,5]) 
y = np.array([4,3,2,9] )

#train-test split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Train the model using the training sets
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
```

Comment: note that using the `statsmodels` package makes this [much easier](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the output vector that you get for variance and co-variance:

```
y_variance = np.mean((y_predict - np.mean(y_predict))**2)

y_covariace = np.mean(y_predict - y_true_values)
```

Note: Co-variance here is mean of change of predictions with respect to there true values.